# Determine the angle of collision of two circles in matter.js

Tags: javascript, collision-detection, collision, matter.js

In this case I need to detect ball collision angle.

```
Events.on(engine, "collisionEnd", event => {
    const pairs = event.pairs
    for (let i = 0; i < pairs.length; i++) {
        const pair = pairs[i];
        const bodies = { bodyA: { ...pair.bodyA }, bodyB: { ...pair.bodyB } }
        for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(bodies)) {
            switch (value.label) {
                case "ball":
                    "<<<<<Determine angle of ball collision>>>>>"
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I use this formula but it didn't work for me.

```
Math.atan(Math.abs(differenceX) / differenceY)
```

Comment: what do you mean by angle of collision, how do you measure it?